# error after installing magento

Tags: magento

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Sns_Avaz_Model_Observer'
>   (T_STRING) in
>   /home/ganyobiclothing/public_html/app/code/local/Sns/Avaz/Model/Observer.php
>   on line 1

Comment: some dependencies might not be there for the theme `SNS Avaz`. check for all extension which are come with `SNS Avaz` theme

Comment: Please someone help...

Comment: have check dependencies?

Comment: Yes, I guess there is error in your file(/app/code/local/Sns/Avaz/Model/Observer.php). Please check this file or provide us code so we can check and let you know exact error.

Comment: First disable this module and check.

Comment: @RameshKumar please see code of observer.php below:                   <?phpclass Sns_Avaz_Model_Observer { public function less_compile($observer) {  $design_package = Mage::getSingleton('core/design_package')->getPackageName();  if($design_package == 'sns_avaz') Mage::helper('avaz/data')->compileLess(); }}

Comment: @urfusion please how do i check the dependencies? also i have provided the observer.php code to see if there is a bug in the code.

Comment: @SatishMantri Magento works fine before the theme was installed so the theme is the problem, so how do i fix it is the issue? please kindly help.

Comment: @ChristopherTheiosEzimoha : check fresh theme folder for missing extension(app/code/local and app/code/community ) which is downloaded by you when you purchase the theme.

Comment: @Christopher Theios Ezimoha, Please do the following and let me know 1.) comment `//Mage::helper('avaz/data')->compileLess();` 2.) After comment if module is working fine then check **compileLess()** function in helper file(/app/code/local/Sns/Avaz/Helper/Data.php)   3.)Don't forget to clear cache......enjoy :)

Comment: @RameshKumar : why you mention me?

Comment: @urfusion, sorry that wasn't  for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is the **sns-avaz-responsive-magento-theme** you should check the following page: http://themeforest.net/item/sns-avaz-responsive-magento-theme/11951628/comments

> Hi,
>
> - This issue only happen with some hosting/server – it compress content file
> - We’ve fixed this issue on v1.0.1. Please try go to file: >/app/code/local/Sns/Avaz/Model/Observer.php open it and add space after re-save.
>
> Ex: "<?php" ==> "<?php "
>
> P/S: See my screenshot: http://take.ms/v8G03 and If your issue still … please
>
> Thanks!
>
> Source: http://themeforest.net/item/sns-avaz-responsive-magento-theme/11951628/comments

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @khoekman the issue has been solved, but am now having issues adding a new attribute based on default, i get timeout error when I click add new attribute set when i refresh the page it shows that the attribute has been added but when i check it is added but without the magento default values, can you help??

Comment: I am transferring my magento site from an old domain to a new domain.

I have exported the databse file from the old server and I have done all the necessary changes.

Now I'm trying to run the exported file into the new database but sql is stock at loading for almost an hour.

Please somebody help.

See loading screen attached.

Thank you.  @SatishMantri

Comment: this has been sorted, just added space on the Observer.php ffile

Answer (score 0):

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Sns_Avaz_Model_Observer' (T_STRING) in /home/ganyobiclothing/public_html/app/code/local/Sns/Avaz/Model/Observer.php on line 1

As its saying on line 1 so probably there is some white space or special character thats resulting in this.

Comment: Thanks @SatishMantri the issue has been solved, but am now having issues adding a new attribute based on default, i get timeout error when I click add new attribute set when i refresh the page it shows that the attribute has been added but when i check it is added but without the magento default values, can you help??

Comment: please see below what I that in the log of the cpanel.

Comment: 66.249.69.32 - - [02/Nov/2015:04:42:57 -0700] "GET /skin/frontend/base/default/images/xmlconnect/tab_shop.png HTTP/1.1" 200 669 "-" "Googlebot-Image/1.0"
180.76.15.19 - - [02/Nov/2015:05:10:38 -0700] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 17032 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Baiduspider/2.0; +http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.html)"
66.249.69.40 - - [02/Nov/2015:05:11:45 -0700] "GET /skin/frontend/default/blue/images/slider_btn_zoom_out.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 432 "-" "Googlebot-Image/1.0"